# validar edad en formulario (ngForm) Angular

Tags: angular, validación

estoy haciendo una practica de Angular y tengo que hacer un formulario con una fecha de nacimiento y comprobar que sea mayor de edad, y si no es mayor de edad que el campo no sea valido y por lo tanto no pueda enviar el formulario. El formulario lo he hecho con TemplateDriven y la clase ngForm.
Gracias por vuestras respuestas

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="fNac">Fecha de Nacimiento: </label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fNac" ngModel name="fNac" required>
</div>
```

Comment: Que tal Alberto, que versión de angular usas????

Comment: Buenas, estoy usando Angular: 7.2.15